# proving matrix invertibility using infinity norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A textbook proved that a matrix $(I-\gamma P)$ is invertible by showing that for any non-zero vector $x \in R^{n}$, then $||(I-\gamma P)x||_{inf} > 0$.

Why does this prove the invertibility?

Comment: If $\max_{i} |(Ax)_i|= 0$, then $Ax=0$ for a nonzero $x$. Thus, $A$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2):

A square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $x \neq 0$ implies that $Ax \neq 0$.  Your textbook proved that if $x \neq 0$, then $\|(I - \gamma P)x\|_\infty > 0$, which means that $(I - \gamma P)x \neq 0$.  So, we can conclude that $I - \gamma P$ is invertible.